# What site is best suited for this type of question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking to ask for some clarification about following paper [Finger trees:
a simple general-purpose data structure](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf) but I'm not sure which StackExchange site best suited for such questions.

Example question:

> What does `-<` symbol denote? A concrete operation or just a shortcut for reducer operation?

Would it best be answered by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) under Haskell tag?
Or perhaps by [Computer Science exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)? Or even [Theoretical Computer Science exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)?

Could anyone point me to the correct site?